# SQL select either table 1 or table 2

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, where-clause

I have two following queries. How can I modify this into single query? The result should be true if either query returns data, and false otherwise:

```
select custId from customer where customerId=3425632456 and custPhone='5653663251';

select accountnumber from account where accountId=524526 and accountPhone='5653663251';
```

Here custPhone=accountPhone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want `exists`:

```
select case 
    when exists (select custId from customer where customerId=3425632456 and custPhone='5653663251') 
        then 1
    when exists (select accountnumber from account where accountId=524526 and accountPhone='5653663251') 
        then 1
    else 0
end res
from dual
```

This query always return a single row, with a single column called `res`. If any of the subqueries returns something, then `res` has value `1`, else `0`.

As a performance bonus for using `case`, the second subquery is not executed if the first succeeds (this is called short-circuit evaluation). If your queries are time consuming, this can be interesting; make sure to put the less expensive query first.

---

If you actually want to return the values, then that's different. One option is `union all`:

```
select custId from customer where customerId=3425632456 and custPhone='5653663251'
union all
select accountnumber from account where accountId=524526 and accountPhone='5653663251'
```

Note that, unlike the first query, this does not guarantee that only one row will be returned. Depending on your data, this could give any number of row, 0 included. You might need additional casting to align the datatypes.

Comment: How can modify above query ,to return custId, accountnumber which are distinct?

Comment: @Rocky4Ever: this is not the question you asked... You said you want true/false result - which is what the above answer gives you.

Comment: Yes.Above query works perfectly in true or false scenario.Can we use same query if we want to return custId or accountnumber?

Comment: But for Union All isn't two table should have same number of columns with same datatypes?

Comment: @Rocky4Ever: the two *subqueries* should return the same number of columns (here, 1 column per subquery), with the same datatype. You might need additional casting to align the datatypes.

Comment: Union All will give 0 even one of the table have record?

Comment: <devil's advocate>The expense argument for ordering queries is balanced by a likelihood of success. If one query takes twice as long as the other to execute, but provides a conclusive result 90% of the time it _might_ be worth putting first, e.g. if the fast query produces a conclusive result 5% of the time.</devil's advocate>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select 
    custId,
    accountnumber 
from customer c
left join account a
on c.custPhone = a.accountPhone
where customerId = 3425632456 
;
```

Comment: what about accountId condition?And what if one table is missing but still another table has record?

Comment: Nope. that is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever this will give you accountNumber and CustId, but seems like you just need to find true/false then my query won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the two tables and check for the count using `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 0
        THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END result,
FROM
    customer c 
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    account a
    ON c.custPhone = a.accountPhone
WHERE c.customerId=3425632456
AND a.accountId=524526
AND c.custPhone='5653663251;
```

Comment: This fails if one table is missing the record.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever That's not possible, it is a FULL OUTER JOIN so records from both tables will be fetched, if none has it then count will be zero and it will display FALSE. That's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Yes I got False even though one table has record and other table is missing.